# Having trouble saving to mongoDB using node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm attempting to save data from an API response and keep getting an empty object. I placed a console.log in my code and it shows that I'm getting a response from the api. I seem to be missing something after the fetch request.

From index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const db = require('./src/models/movie')
require('./src/db/mongoose')
const Movie = require('./src/models/movie')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

// APP CONFIG
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

// ROUTES - ADD
app.post('/movies/:imdbID', (req, res) => {
    const imdb = req.params.imdbID
    const url = `**api link and key**${imdb}`

    const movie = fetch(url).then((res) => {
        return res.json()
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        const addMovie = new Movie(response)
        db.Movie.create(addMovie, (err, newMovie) => {
            if(err){
                res.render('movie404')
            } else {
                res.redirect('/')
            }
        })
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(500).send(e)
    }) 
})
```

From mongoose.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/movietime-api', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
})
```

From details.handlebars:

```
<h2>{{details.Title}}</h2>
<img src="{{details.Poster}}" alt="{{details.Title}}">
<p><em>{{details.Plot}}</em></p>
<p>Starring: {{details.Actors}}</p>
<p>Director: {{details.Director}}</p>
<form action="/movies/{{details.imdbID}}" method="POST">
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

From movie.js:

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

```
// MONGOOSE/MODEL CONFIG
const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie',{
    imdbID: String,
    Title: String,
    Poster: String,
    Director: String,
    Year: String,
    Plot: String,
    Ratings: String,
    Rated: String,
    Genre: String,
    Writer: String,
    Actors: String
});

module.exports = Movie;
```

I would expect a redirect to the index page then a new database entry using the above model.

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there just few thing needs to be taken care of:

```js
app.post('/movies/:imdbID', (req, res) => {
    const imdb = req.params.imdbID
    const url = `**api link and key**${imdb}`

    const movie = fetch(url).then((res) => {
        return res.json()
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        const addMovie = new Movie(response)

        addMovie.save((err, newMovie) => {
            if(err){
                res.render('movie404',newMovie) // to render the details
            } else {
                res.redirect('/')
            }
        })
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(500).send(e)
```

[ref](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save)